# Macro log2 used without args error with cimg?

Tags: c++, g++, header-files, cimg

So I got myself g++ for windows following [this.](http://www.claremontmckenna.edu/pages/faculty/alee/g++/g++.html)

Since I wanted to experiment with CImg I downloaded the beta from [here.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cimg/files/)

I simply copied the cimg.h into g++'s include directory and also put some dependencies it couldn't find when compiling there.

However now when I try to compile something that uses cimg like [this tutorial.](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/reference/group__cimg__tutorial.html)

It gives me the error:

```
\Cimg.h:14485: macro 'log2' used without args
```

and the same for line 14492.

These lines look like so:

```
CImg<T>& log2() {
  cimg_for(*this,ptrd,T) *ptrd = (T)cimg::log2((double)*ptrd);
  return *this;
}

//! Compute the base-10 logarithm of each pixel value \newinstance.
CImg<Tfloat> get_log2() const {
  return CImg<Tfloat>(*this,false).log2();
}
```

This is literally the first time I use C++, so obviously I am already confused by the concept of all the header files and such, so I might be doing something wrong there. Or I may aswell be making a silly beginner mistake.

Comment: Someone is doing a `#define log2(x) something` in a header included before this. It interferes with the functions defined here. Perhaps you shouldn't have put everything in the compiler's include directory?

Comment: @BoPersson What other ways of putting it do I have? As I said this is the first time I am using C++ so I don't know so many ways of including header files.

Comment: It is common to put each library in its own directory, and point the compiler there with a `-I directory` option. I'm not sure if that's your problem here, but it *might* be.

Comment: I removed all the header files I had put before from the include directory to a directory of their own and pointed the compiler to it using `-I directory` as you said, however I still get the same error.

Comment: Most likely, there's a "log2" in some headerfile that you are including [directly or indirectly]. You can either use `#undef log2` or, my suggestion, name your log2 function something different.

Comment: Well it's not my log2 function but Cimg's, so I don't think I can name it otherwise. I guess I'll go try undef.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is one header included before CImg.h that apparently does a

```
#define log2 something
```

you may try to change the order of the includes, so that this header does the #define after the #include "CImg.h".
Looks like the error does not come from CImg though.